# Meaning of the verb "swing" in “How they swinging that?”

Tags: meaning-in-context, slang

It was in the 12th episode of the 3rd season of *Breaking Bad*. Here is the context:

> Hank: How is your old man?
>
> Back teaching?
>
> Walt Jr: No. l don't think either of them are working right now.
>
> Hank: How they **swinging** that?
>
> Walt Jr: I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means "How are they managing to do that?"

[American Heritage Dictionary "swing" 7a](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=swing)
7. Informal
a. To manage or arrange successfully: *swing a deal*.

Comment: I'm not completely clear as to how the BrE slang usage [***to swing the lead***](https://www.grammar-monster.com/sayings_proverbs/swing_the_lead.htm#:~:text=What%20Is%20the%20Origin%20of,attached%20to%20a%20long%20rope.&text=Therefore%2C%20a%20sailor%20who%20was%20swinging%20the%20lead%20was%20being%20lazy.) ties in with OP's example. Probably completely unrelated. But I was gratified to discover just now that the full OED has my favourite "synonym" for ***swing*** in this sense - ***wangle***.

Comment: @FFRM That's a new one to me. Probably not related to "get the lead out". https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+the+lead+out